# SharePoint Designer has stopped working

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I'm having an issue with SharePoint Designer. This is for SharePoint online

From "Send Email" action>To> when I click on "people/groups from SharePoint Site. SharePoint Designer crashes. I get a message "SP Designer has stopped working "

I've spent a few hours trying to figure out the issue. I found a few blogs with similar issues and they are talking about the IIS being set up for two web site binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean designer cache and check.

- Close SPD2013
- Delete everything at
  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
- Delete everything at %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache
- Go to SPD2013 options –> General –> Application Options –> Uncheck
  the “Cache site data across SharePoint Designer sessions”